# How to get the last option value from a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I have a `DropDownList` with the following options:

```
o select
1 hot
2 cold
3 warm
```

How can I get the last option value ("warm") from the `DropDownList`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you have a variable referenced to your DropDownList:

```
if (myDropDownList.Items.Count > 0)
{
    string myValue = myDropDownList.Items[myDropDownList.Items.Count - 1].Value;
}
```

Note that you should probably check that the DropDownList has items first, or else this will throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception when the list is empty. Thanks @Cylon.

Comment: Check for an empty list first?

Answer (score 2):

```
var last = cmbMyList.Items.OfType<ListItem>().LastOrDefault();
```

*(Thanks to Cylon Cat for correcting me)*

Very Simple

Comment: var last = cmbMyList.Items.OfType<ListItem>().LastOrDefault(); // the ListItemCollection isn't generic; you have to make a generic collection before you can use LINQ functions onit.

Answer (score 1):

Something like 
`cboTemp.SelectedIndex = cboTemp.Items.Count -1;`